# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-Zero_balance_Account__each_CSP_ VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL AFTER Comm_id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
  <?php
                            include 'includes/connection.php';

                            if (isset($_POST['add_head'])) {
                                $head_name = $_POST['new_head'];
                                $cat_value = $_POST['SelectCat'];

                                $head_db_name = preg_replace('/([^A-Za-z0-9\-])/', '_', $head_name);

                                $sql = "INSERT INTO catcom (ComName, ComFullName, cat_id) VALUES ('$head_db_name', '$head_name','$cat_value')   ";

                                if ($cid -> query($sql) === TRUE) {

                                    $sql = "ALTER TABLE commissions ADD $head_db_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL AFTER Comm_id";
                                    if ($cid -> query($sql) == TRUE) {
                                        echo "<span> Head has been Added </span> ";
                                        header("Refresh: 1; url=CommEdit.php");
                                    } else {
                                          echo  mysqli_error($cid);
                                    }

                                } else {
                                 mysqli_error($cid);                                }

                                $cid -> close();

                            } 
                            ?>
```

When i am input the String is account_value 
its work and when i am putting value account_amount( this is new value)

shows error: `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-Zero_balance_Account__each_CSP_ VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL AFTER Comm_id`

Comment: Put `echo $sql` before executing the query and update your question with the full query text.

Comment: i found the Answer thanks for you response, just change  preg_replace('/([^A-Za-z0-9\-])/', '_', $head_name);      with in this place $head_db_name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '_', $head_name);  finally my program file is running !!